# How to use RewriteRule in htaccess using XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I get rid of the folder name using .htaccess and XAMPP.

I saved the folder in --> xampp/htdocs/myproject

In myproject folder there are an `index.php` and `.htaccess` files.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
<h1>index</h1>


<?php   

    var_dump($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

This redirects me to the index file but when i var_dump requested uri i'm getting also myfoler name.

example:

```
http://localhost/myproject/contact
```

i'm getting -->`/myproject/contact`

Is this possible to get rid of this foldername/path using .htaccess ?
In this case the `/myproject/`.

Comment: Use `$_GET['url']`

Comment: You will have your request uri in your $_GET['url'] as you have specified in your RewriteRule. So which way do you want to be using this?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^myproject/(.*)$  $1
```

This will take any url of the pattern "myproject/whatever" and rewrite it as "whatever". The string (.*) tells .htaccess to take everything after "myproject/" and store it in a backreference, which is referred to in the rewrite portion of the rule as $1. Hope this helps.